# Presenting Modalviewcontroller for Info Button when pressed on UIToolbar programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I want is on main window to present the created modalViewController view when the infobutton is pressed. But when I press Info button on the main window nothing happens.

In the mainviewcontroller.h file I have following code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface imageviewViewController : UIViewController{
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIToolbar *toolbar;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIBarButtonSystemItem currentSystemItem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

@end
```

In the mainviewcontroller.m file have following code:

```
#import "imageviewViewController.h"
#import "Infoviewcontroller.h"


@implementation imageviewViewController

@synthesize toolbar;
@synthesize currentSystemItem;
@synthesize audioPlayer;

UIBarButtonItem *infoItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                          initWithTitle:@"Info" 
                          style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                          target:nil 
                          action:@selector(Infobuttonpressed)]; 

  // flex item used to put space in between buttons

    UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                             initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                             target:nil
                             action:nil];

    //Add buttons to the array

    NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: settingsButton, flexItem, systemItem, flexItem, systemItem1,flexItem, systemItem2, flexItem, systemItem3, flexItem, infoItem, nil];

     [toolbar setItems:toolbarItems];

    [settingsButton release];
    [systemItem  release];
    [systemItem1 release];
    [systemItem2 release];
    [systemItem3 release];
    [infoItem release];
    [flexItem release];

[super viewDidLoad];  

}


- (void) Infobuttonpressed: (id) sender
{
Infoviewcontroller *myView = [[Infoviewcontroller alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES]; // present view modally
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myView animated:YES]; // add to navigation stack
[myView release];
}
```

In the Infoviewcontroller.h file have following code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Infoviewcontroller : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>

{

UITextView *textView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *textView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UINavigationBar *navBar;


@end
```

Then in the infoviewcontroller.m file have the following code:

```
#import "Infoviewcontroller.h"

@implementation Infoviewcontroller

@synthesize textView;
@synthesize navBar;



-(void)dealloc
{
[textView release];
    [navBar release];
[super dealloc];
}

 -(void)setupTextView
  {
self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame] autorelease];

self.textView.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"System Bold" size:13];

self.textView.delegate = self;

self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.textView.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;

self.textView.text = @"This is UITextView\nThis is UITextView\nThis is UITextView\nThis is UITextView"; 

[self.view addSubview: self.textView];    

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
UINavigationItem *navItem = [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"ModalViewControllerTest"] autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *done = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissView:)] autorelease];
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = done;
navBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem];
[self.view addSubview:navBar];
}
```

Comment: Does your info view controller have a nib file or are you building it all in code?

Comment: And have you checked using breakpoints to see how far you get? Is the action method executed, which methods in the controller are executed?

Comment: Also, you should be creating your subviews in loadView, not viewDidLoad, it's what it's there for of you're not using a nib.

Comment: It is not executing action method and it is not even executing infoviewcontroller.h and .m files. I dont get it why

Comment: Can you show the code where you declare the info button and add it to the toolbar, in your sample above it is not shown as part of a method, is that right?

Comment: i just added the code you requested in it. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *infoItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                          initWithTitle:@"Info" 
                          style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                          target:nil 
                          action:@selector(Infobuttonpressed)];
```

Should be

```
UIBarButtonItem *infoItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                          initWithTitle:@"Info" 
                          style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                          target:self
                          action:@selector(Infobuttonpressed:)];
```

Spot the difference? First, you're missing a target (should be `self`, not `nil`). Second, the colon at the end of the selector is part of the signature, you were missing it so it was not calling your method (which is `InfoButtonPressed:(id)sender`).

As an aside, methods should start with a lower case name.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need both pushModalViewController and pushViewController

Assuming your views are already controlled within an instance of a UINavigationController pushModalViewController on its own will work.

edit - remove the reference to pushViewController. Does it now work?

```
-(void) Infobuttonpressed: (id) sender; 
{ Infoviewcontroller *myView = [[Infoviewcontroller alloc] init]; 
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView];
UIViewController *pushController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self addSubview:pushController.view];
[pushController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[myView release]; 
}
```

Comment: I am not getting you. If you can explain more in detail. I will appreciate it. Thanks for help though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But still after removing the pushviewcontroller sentence still didnt work.

Comment: hmm, does it work if you just push the view onto the navigation controller without the presentModal line?

Comment: i removed the presentmodalviewcontroller sentence as you suggested but still no success. Thanks for ur help. I appreciate.

Comment: am away from my mac, so can't test but think the above should now work for you. Its all in how you setup your view controller stack.

Comment: now i m getting a message that instance method addsubview not found

Comment: ahh, good call to add the declaration of the info button, makes sense now. ignore everything I said ;-) listen to fishinear and jrturton.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6489/discussion-between-user1120133-and-nik-burns)

Answer (score 0):

The target of your infoItem is set to nil. You should set this to an instance of the class where the Infobuttonpressed is defined. I assume that is the mainviewController?

Also, the selector to call is specified as: @selector(Infobuttonpressed), while the method is called "Infobuttonpressed:", that is, with a parameter. That will likely result in a runtime error once you fix the target.

Then, there are some peculiarities in the way you handle things. As Nik already answered, you need to choose whether you want to present the view modally (with presentModalViewController), or present it as part of the navigation stack (with pushViewController), you cannot do both.

If you present it as part of the navitation stack, then it already has a navigation bar, and so you should not add one yourself. Just set the properties of the self.navigationItem.

Have a look at the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1) for more info.